assert (!isnan(x)) succeeds but printf("%f",x) shows -nan
I am using gcc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0.
Ubuntu 24.04
I have a bug in my code where a numerical analysis function is giving very different answers.
Each of the following returns true. x is a double.
assert (fpclassify(x) == FP_NORMAL);;
assert (x == x);
assert (!(isnan(x)));
assert (isnormal(x));

uint64_t abc = *((long long*)&x) ;
printf("%" PRIx64 "\n", abc);
/* Prints fff8000000000000 */
printf("%f",x);
/* Prints -nan */
uint64_t x4 = 0xfff8000000000000;
assert (x4 == abc);

I am calling the C code from OCaml so it is possible that the OCaml runtime is messing with the values.
Could this be a compiler bug or are here other explanations?
Edit: A previous version of this post mistakenly used bitwise negation instead of Boolean negation.

Please note that both isnan and isnormal returns a non-zero integer value if the predicate is "true". That means the bit-wise operator ~ might not give you a zero from it. If you want a logical complement use !.

Don't use bitwise complement (~) for isnan and isnormal.  Use logical complement (!).  Bitwise complement will probably always return a logical true value for those (e.g. ~1 is -2, not 0 as you seem to think).

When you encounter something like this, do not just wonder at the result and post to Stack Overflow. Dissect the problem into pieces. Print each individual result directly, as in printf("%d/n", isnormal(x)); and printf("%d/n", ~isnormal(x));, to see what is going on. And look up the documentation for the functions and operators you are working with.

@EricPostpischil Thank you, I have corrected the post to replace bitwise negation with boolean negation and include the value printed by printf.

You're sure that you don't have NDEBUG defined, so that the asserts are really doing something?  Can you make a [mcve] that can be compiled and run to reproduce the issue?

@NateEldredge When I edit any line to assert the negation, the program halts with "Assertion failed:". Specifically, any of the statements assert (x !=x); assert (fpclassify(x) != FP_NORMAL), assert ((isnan(x))); assert (!isnormal(x)); cause "Assertion failed, Aborted (core dumped)".

@PatrickNicodemus What we're asking for is a self-contained piece of code that others can compile and run without modification and see the same result you do.

Also include your compiler flags, library and OS version, etc.  In particular, if you're using -ffast-math or -ffinite-math-only or -Ofast, you're telling the compiler to assume that NaNs never occur, and then isnan(x) is optimized out to constant 0, so contradictory results would be expected if you do have a NaN.

Once again, compiler flags, please?  And a [mcve].  It is very frustrating to try and help someone when every time you ask for more information, they provide only half of it.

Nate, I understand your frustration. I am in the process of collecting the information you asked for. I am looking into an error in a large open-source software project. The default compiler flags used by the build tool appear to be here. https://github.com/owlbarn/owl/blob/06943b0267e7e80dd0eba94ebf63ca4d25c71910/INSTALL.md?plain=1#L18

As a matter of fact I spent multiple hours yesterday evening extracting the buggy code from the context of the larger project and making it into a standalone executable. Unfortunately when I pulled the code out of its original context, the bug disappeared, and so the minimization was not useful.

@PatrickNicodemus -ffast-math, for code that claims "Our mission is to push the frontier of high-performance scientific computing, provide both researchers and industry programmers a powerful framework to write concise, fast and safe analytical code."?!?!  Oooof.  See Can -ffast-math be safely used on a typical project?  TLDR: No.

Thank you for the link Andrew, looks worrying. @NateEldredge In the meantime as I attempt to minimize the bug, the best I can do is direct you to the github issue I created, documenting my progress on working through the bug. https://github.com/owlbarn/owl/issues/665

Okay, thanks.  In the future, if you only have part of the requested information available, you can include in your edit something like "I am still trying to find out X", so that people know they're not being ignored.

@PatrickNicodemus "Edit: A previous version of this post mistakenly used bitwise negation instead of Boolean negation" --> that is poor etiquette once answers arrive and do a dis-service to this and that.  Better to have left code as it was - or perhaps append an update.

Per your comments, it appears your code is being built with -Ofast -ffast-math.  From the gcc manual, these enable -ffinite-math-only, whose behavior is:

Allow optimizations for floating-point arithmetic that assume that arguments and results are not NaNs or +-Infs.

The compiler is not buggy; it's behaving as documented.  But you've broken your contract with the compiler by promising that NaN will never appear, and then using one anyway.
In particular, among the optimizations in question is that isnan(x) will be optimized to constant 0, so that it appears to return false even when x really is a NaN; x == x will be optimized to constant 1; and isnormal and fpclassify will not check for NaN.  Hence the contradictory results you are observing.
Try rebuilding without these options (-O3 is safe) and you should see the assertions fail.

Disabling -Ofast -ffast-math made the code behave in the expected way. It also solved the original bug where a function was returning -nan instead of the expected. I have written this up on the linked github issue and proposed removing -Ofast and -ffast-math from the default build flags.

Incidentally, clang will warn about uses of isnan() and isinf() when -ffast-math is in effect.

Each of the issomething floating-point classification macros “returns a nonzero value if and only if its argument” is in the tested category (C 2018 subclauses in 7.12.3). So it does not necessarily produce 0 or 1. It may produce 2, 4, or other numbers.
When you apply the bitwise complement operator, ~, to these, a zero value will produce a non-zero result, but 1, 2, 4, and most other values will also produce non-zero results; the result will have bits that were on in the operand turned off but bits that were off turned on, usually yielding a non-zero number.
With two’s complement, only the value equal to ~0, −1, will produce a zero result.
To test the inverse of isnormal, you can use the Boolean negation: !isnormal(x).

Thank you very much. The post has been updated to remove this mistake

The ~ operator is bitwise complement -- it flips all bits of the value -- not logical not.  So applying it to a "boolean" value will rarely do what you want.  For example, the program:
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    if (~true) {
        printf("~true is true\n");
    }
}

will print ~true is true

Thank you very much. The post has been updated to remove this mistake
